Some tag synonyms I found
bitmain -> antminer
bip-37 -> bloom-filter
bip-70 -> payment-protocol
wif -> wallet-import-format
fraud -> scam
seed -> deterministic-wallets
hacking -> hack
On the contrary, I still don't have the Synonymizer badge :(

On first look, I only disagree with the seed->deterministic-wallets change. I can see both tags being useful on their own, it is possible to ask a question about seeds without any reference/relevance to an HD wallet, and vice versa.

Did you know that you can propose synonyms directly on tags?

Other users can then vote on your synonyms, they don't have to be created by mods necessarily. ;)
In case you had done that already and nobody noticed yet, I'll have to look into how proposed synonyms get voted on. Anyway, I can take a look at these a little later today, although I think some of them should be switched in direction.

Update:
I've created the following synonyms:

wif -> wallet-import-format
scam -> fraud

I've merged the following tags:

bip-37 & bloom-filter -> bip37-bloom-filter
bip-70 & payment-protocol -> bip70-payment-protocol
bitmain -> antminer

I've also cleaned the questions for which the tag improvements weren't fitting. I have not adopted the seed and hacking changes yet, I'm not sure they are improvements.

"Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag" for all of them. So, I couldn't merge any of them.

Ah, thanks, I didn't realize.

Would suggest hack -> hacking rather than what was originally proposed.

Yeah, that one as well as scam and fraud were the one that I meant should be switched in direction.
